# Does Ant guarantee order of filesets?

Tags: java, ant, copy, fileset

in our project we use Ant to distribute files. There is hierarchy of files, and they overwrite files from previous level. Like this: default - level1 - level2. Currently it is made the way:

```
<copy todir="...">
 <fileset dir="${root}/default" includes="**/*" excludes="file1" />
 <fileset dir="${root}/level1" includes="**/*" />
 <fileset dir="${root}/level2" includes="**/*" excludes="file2"/>
</copy>
```

So we expected that all the folders contain file with the same name, it will be taken from level2 directory.

Not long ago we moved to a new build box with another version of Java and we discovered that the order of filesets is broken.

Is there a way to fix this issue without modifying ant config files? We have a big number of it. If there is no way, how can I got it off cheap? Thank you.

Comment: See [ant copy copying order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716398/ant-copy-copying-order) for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the order of filesets is quaranteed, but the order of copy tasks is.
So, following the suggestion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/671944/578759), it might be a good idea to write several copy tasks with overwrite="true":

```
<copy todir="...">
  <fileset dir="${root}/default" includes="**/*" excludes="file1" />
</copy>
<copy todir="...">
  <fileset dir="${root}/level1" includes="**/*" overwrite="true" />
</copy>
<copy todir="...">
  <fileset dir="${root}/level2" includes="**/*" excludes="file2" overwrite="true" />
</copy>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap a `sort` resource collection around your `fileset`s and ensure the order used by copy this way. Sort itself only likes a single resource collection as child element, so you need to wrap the `fileset` inside a `union` or `resources` container.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#sort

Something like

```
<sort>
  <resources>
    <fileset dir="${root}/default" includes="**/*" excludes="file1" />
    <fileset dir="${root}/level1" includes="**/*" />
    <fileset dir="${root}/level2" includes="**/*" excludes="file2"/>
  </resources>
  <name/>
</sort>
```

to sort the files by name.

Comment: "sort expects exactly one nested resource collection." - I can not pass two filesets to it

Comment: but a `union` of 'fileset's - or if you care for duplicate names a `resources` of `fileset`s.